# Webscraping using jsoup html parsing question

Tags: java, eclipse, web, jsoup, screen-scraping

I have a spring boot app that scrapes a website and I can get it to work but cant seem to figure out how to get to the inner html elements to iterate through. Seems like I always just reach the outter html stuff only. Below is my code

```
private void fetchData() {
    try {
        Document doc =
                Jsoup.connect("https://www.i-90motorsports.com/default.asp?page=xPreOwnedInventory").userAgent("Mozilla/17.0").get();

        Elements elementList = doc.select("doc.info"); 
        Elements vehBody = doc.select("div#VehBody"); 
        if(doc.getAllElements().isEmpty()) {
            aStringBuilder.append("Nothing found for " );
            addLineBreak();
            return;
        }   
        for(Element anElement : vehBody) {
            //if(isElementValid(anElement)) {
                aStringBuilder.append(anElement.getElementsByTag("a").first().text() ); 
                addLineBreak();
            //}
        } 
        aStringBuilder.append("Finished Scraping websites. Found  "+ elementList.size() +" elements");
        addLineBreak();

    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(  );
    }

}
```

This is the html I am trying to get. I am trying to iterate through each vehicle row and not sure which value to enter in the "select" part. Suggestions?

```
<div id="VehBody">


<div class="vehicle_row dspYear-2020 dspCondition-PREOWNED dspBodyType-SNOWMOBILE dspSubType-MOUNTAIN dspMake-SKI-DOO dspModel-SUMMIT-X-850-E-TEC-175-SS-POWDERMAX-LIGHT-3-0-S-LEV-BLUE images-1" rel="8382204"><div class="unitImage"><div class="imageRow">
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `<div id="VehBody">` is an **empty element** that is **filled via JavaScript** and can therefore not being read by jsoup (which is for reading the pages source, not for reading the DOM modified by JavaScript). Instead, you might get the data you want by parsing [the JavaScript file that is included at the end of the header](http://view-source:https://www.i-90motorsports.com/imglib/Inventory/cache/2366/UVehInv.js?v=1892194):

```html
<script id='jsCachedFile' src='/imglib/Inventory/cache/2366/UVehInv.js?v=1892194' type='text/javascript' ></script></head>
```

Please note that the parameter `v` is changing each time requesting the HTML page.